# Spring Security Service with Grails - Get current user 'NULL' error

Tags: grails, spring-security

Hi I am trying out Spring Security Core with Grails and trying to get the current logged in user. However, I get java.lang.NullPointerException, which was caused by: Cannot get property 'principal' on null object.

The following is my code:

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
@Transactional
class MyController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: 
                            "DELETE"]

    def test(){
         def springSecurityService
         render "Current User is: [" + springSecurityService.principal  
                                  + "]"
         }
    }
```

For some reasons springSecurityService is null. What did I miss?

Please advise. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `def springSecurityService` should be outside of your method `test()` at the class level.

Comment: Thank you so much Joshua! This works! Really appreciate it!

Comment: When you are putting that in class level you are actually injecting a spring service bean into your controller bean class which is equivalent/same as spring autowired. But inside method it's just a variable.

Comment: Thanks Mamum! Appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Joshua Moore, this worked! Thank you so much!

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
@Transactional
class MyController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def springSecurityService

    def test(){



        render "Current User is: [" + springSecurityService.principal  + "]"


    }

}
```